# Cental Administration / Search / Team Site — different web applications or single (SPF 2013)?

Tags: search, central-administration, web-application

We have migrated from SPS 2007 to SPF 2013 and didn't using guides, "best practices", migration tools. Now we have only one web application "Central Administration" with CA and content web-sites on it.

Next we want to install "Search". But some solutions say "to create new web application for it".

So now we are in doubt. Should we choose to separate CA, content and search between different web applications or not? (I guess so, but having small experience)

Will be appreciative of your help.

Comment: Do you really mean you moved from SharePoint Server 2007 to SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Comment: Right. We had to "upgrade" our corporate intranet website in all senses (and get rid of "heavy" licensing). Although with our small experience we just did common data, views and files migration (without something special).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFIK, You can create site collections in the Central Admin web but it is not recommend.Simple reason(best practice) always keep Central admin on the APP servers while other content driven site collections hosted on the WFE. Central admin site is only for farm administrator not for every body.

Another Risk involved is you may expose your central to all the users, sometime i saw people adding the user in the web application's policy that's way you central admin can be accessed by those user.

- Create A new web application for the team site.
- Move your existing site from Central admin to new Web App.
- You can create another web app for search or simply create a site
  collection using search center template under your new web app.

Answer (score 0):

This is really dependent on how you want things set up. There's no 'right answer', but here's some considerations:

- Each web application gets their own application pool. If everything is under the same web application, they are all under the same application pool - if this application pool stops working, everything stops working. If you really want things to be up as much as possible, without risks, then create separate web applications!
- Each application pool has an overhead (for example, each one will 'reserve'..... 5MB (as an example) of space for applications to run in. This 5MB will stay reserved and cannot be accessed by other applications, so if you have three web applications, you have fenced off 15MB for them). If you have a lot of space, this shouldn't be a concern unless you have hundreds of web applications.
- Are you trying to create a search center site [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582314(v=office.15).aspx] (since you mentioned creating a web application for it)? If not, I don't think you really need to....

I'm still learning, so if anyone sees anything erroneous with my message, please let me know :) I'd like to learn, too.